# how I can show the sum of in a datagridview column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to show the sum of the `count` column from this `datagridview`, but I don't know how I can get to the data in the datagridview.

When I click on the button, I want to show `94` in `label1`.

How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: @manhaz: welcome to StackOverflow! Consider upvoting answers to your other questions, and the best one, you should be marking as 'accepted answer' with the green checkmark. It'll help ensure you get good answers to future questions!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
label1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Answer (score 32):

Fast and clean way using LINQ

```
int total = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells[1].Value));
```

verified on VS2013

Answer (score 17):

If your grid is bound to a `DataTable`, I believe you can just do:

```
// Should probably add a DBNull check for safety; but you get the idea.
long sum = (long)table.Compute("Sum(count)", "True");
```

If it *isn't* bound to a table, you could easily make it so:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("count", typeof(int));

// This will automatically create the DataGridView's columns.
dataGridView.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: I'm reminded of the reason I'm here... I never even realized a `Compute` function existed on the DataTable object!

Answer (score 9):

Use LINQ if you can.

```
  label1.Text =  dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                   .AsEnumerable()
                                   .Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
                                   .ToString();
```

Comment: Can a `DataGridViewRow` ever be cast to a `DataRow`?

Comment: But... but... is there a `Field` extension method on `DataGridViewRow`?

Answer (score 3):

```
 decimal Total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Total+= Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value);
  }

labelName.Text = Total.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the total row to your data collection that will be bound to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it better with two datagridview, you add the same datasource , hide the headers of the second, set the height of the second = to the height of the rows of the first, turn off all resizable atributes of the second, synchronize the scrollbars of both, only horizontal, put the second on the botton of the first etc.

take a look:

```
   dgv3.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
   dgv3.Height = dgv1.Rows[0].Height;
   dgv3.Location = new Point(Xdgvx, this.dgv1.Height - dgv3.Height - SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight);
   dgv3.Width = dgv1.Width;

   private void dgv1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {
                dgv3.HorizontalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//declare the total variable
int total = 0;
//loop through the datagrid and sum the column 
for(int i=0;i<datagridview1.Rows.Count;i++)
{       
   double.TryParse(datagridview1.Rows[i].Cells["CELL NAME OR INDEX"].Value.ToString(),out int cellValue)
    total +=total;    
}
//you can use the total here
 lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you can accomplish this by Using LINQ like so the next code

```cs
label1.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in datagridview1.Rows
                                 where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString())
                                 select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
```