# Calculate total of a column using linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a structure like

```
ID  Description Principal   Interest    Total
123 Paid        100          150        250
    Balance     50           50         100
    Total        ?            ?           ?
124 Paid        100          150        250
    Balance     50           50         100
    Total        ?            ?           ?
```

Class :

```
public class APIBillingHistory
{
    public List<APIBillingHistoryDetails> BillingHistoryDetails;
}

public class APIBillingHistoryDetails
{
    public string BillId;
    public string Description;
    public Decimal Principal;
    public Decimal Interest;
    public Decimal Total;
}
```

**I would like to sum value for each column for each id**. So in above example, `Total` for ID 123 for `Principal` would be 150, `Interest` 200 likewise.  I checked this solution over here [How to create Total column and Total row using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596761/1169180) but not able to get it.

Code:

```
responseObj = new APIBillingHistory
{
    BillingHistoryDetails = billingHistory.BillingHistoryDetails
            .GroupBy(detail => new { detail.BillId, detail.Description})
            .Select(group => new APIBillingHistoryDetails
            {
                BillId = group.Key.BillId,
                Description = group.Key.Description,
                Principal = group.Sum(t => t.Principal),
                Interest = group.Sum(t => t.Interest),
                Total = group.Sum(t => t.Principal) + group.Sum(t => t.Interest)
            }).Concat(new APIBillingHistoryDetails
            {
                Description = "Total",
                /*  Not sure what to write over here */
            })
};
```

Edit:

To clarify what I am trying to achieve:

- My source record list does not contain "Total" column & "Total" row. I would like to add it manually.
- I Was able to figure out how to Add "Total" column which would contain Sum of values.
- `Principal` & `Interest` will contain values in `decimal` format.
- `ID` column is an integer. I would like to Display Total row for each `ID`
- Values for `Principal` & `Interest` are being calculated by aggregating based on `ID`, After that calculation, only `Total` row should get displayed.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What does the ID column equals for the second and third rows? How can a `Decimal` be a `?` ? Do you want to sum `Total` or did you mean the 'Total' row isn't in your source data?

Comment: Also, does your source data already include the `Total` field for each row, or does that have to be added as well?

Comment: I'd like to recommend using a tool called LinqPad.  It's like using Sql Server Management Studio but on C# entities. Allows you to visualise the results of you LINQ expressions and really get to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the current data

```
BillId Description Principal   Interest
123    Paid        100          150    
123    Balance     50           50     
124    Paid        100          150     
124    Balance     50           50
```

Then just group by the identity, creating the total object by summing up the grouped properties setting the description as **"Total"**.

```
var totalsObj = new APIBillingHistory {
    BillingHistoryDetails = billingHistory.BillingHistoryDetails
           .GroupBy(detail => detail.BillId)
           .Select(g => new APIBillingHistoryDetails {
             BillId = g.Key,
             Description = "Total",
             Principal = g.Sum(detail => detail.Principal),
             Interest = g.Sum(detail => detail.Interest),
             Total = g.Sum(detail => detail.Principal) + g.Sum(detail => detail.Interest)
           }).ToList()
};
```

and  `totalsObj.BillingHistoryDetails` would have desired out put

> After that calculation, only Total row should get displayed.

```
BillId Description Principal   Interest    Total
123    Total       150         200         350
124    Total       150         200         350
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Concat` and reference previous data. You need to use `SelectMany`:

```
BillingHistoryDetails = billingHistory.BillingHistoryDetails
    .GroupBy(detail => detail.BillId)
    .SelectMany(bg => bg.Concat(new[] { new APIBillingHistoryDetails {
        BillId = bg.First().BillId,
        Description = "Total",
        Principal = bg.Sum(b => b.Principal),
        Interest = bg.Sum(b => b.Interest),
        Total = bg.Sum(b => b.Total)
    } }));
```

Comment: I can't avoid `Select` as I am doing aggregate on `Principal` and `Interest` group by `ID`. After doing that aggregate I would like to calculate the total for each column.

Comment: That is not evident in your question.

Comment: I think it needs better editing; for example, LINQ doesn't "display" anything.