# Calculate total from datagridview into textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

i have a datagridview which are used to display a transaction record.
And one of the columns in datagridview is "Total", which is "SubTotal" times with "Quantity".

My question is, how do i gonna make "GrandTotal" by calculating all "Total" in datagridview into textbox?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

if you see in the datagridview above, there is column named "Total", this "Total" was got from "Quantity" times "SubTotal", what i want is i want to calculate the "Total" (Sum all of the "Total" in the column) into textbox.

How do i gonna do that?

I already thought about it, but i cannot came with an idea how do i calculate (sum) the "Total" column in the datagridview into the textbox.

I appreciate your answer.
Thank you very much!

Comment: See this similar article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779729/how-i-can-show-the-sum-of-in-a-datagridview-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how I can show the sum of in a datagridview column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779729/how-i-can-show-the-sum-of-in-a-datagridview-column)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through each row and find cell which hold the total value. convert this total value to double(any numeric data structure) and calculate grand total by adding each one with previous grand total.

**Without Linq**

```
    double result = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView.Rows)
    {
        result += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Total"].Value);
    }
```

**With Linq**

```
    double result = DataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(row => Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Total"].Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are binding a List or DataTable then just simply use LINQ's [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) method

Comment: This would be the best solution rather than iterating through grid view rows.

Answer (score 0):

// You can use it in the click event of button

```
str = "YOUR SQL QUERY";
objCom = new SqlCommand(str, objCon);
objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objCom);
objDataSet = new DataSet();
objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "TABLE NAME");
dataGridView2.DataMember = "TABLE NAME";
dataGridView2.DataSource = objDataSet;
dataGridView2[3, dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Value = "Total";
dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Style.ForeColor =     Color.White;
dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
double sum = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; row++)
{
  sum = sum + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value);
} 
dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[4].Value = sum.ToString();
```