# Testing for last entry blank objects in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

Good Morning;

I'm getting some odd behavior testing for blank object values in a DataGridView using a DataSet to import xml to the DataGridView. I'm just beginning to look into using DataGridView in my WinForm. I created the very simple DataGridView using the AuthorsDataSet walkthrough

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekw4dh3f.aspx

Then I manipulated the code, very minorly, to read my xml file instead of the AuthorsDataSet. Works Great.

Then I try to sum all of the items in one column. I found this and it got me to the point I'm at.

[how I can show the sum of in a datagridview column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779729/how-i-can-show-the-sum-of-in-a-datagridview-column)

That brings me to here

```
    public string sum()
    {

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            var test = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value; //Can not use
                //double here as I get the FromatException whether 
                //testing for `==null` or `==""`

            //double test = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value); THIS THROWS FormatException

            if (test == "")
            {
                sum += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(test);
            }
        }
        return sum.ToString();
    }
```

If I use the `double test...` and the `if (test == null)` I get `FormatException was unhandled` Ultimately what I have works, but I'm concerned for other errors in the future. The concern lies in that the xml object I'm testing for could have no value and I'm not sure where to go with it. Should I assign it a value of 0 and then write over it when the user provides input (in this case it's a simple start/stop timer.)

If I just use `sum += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);` without testing for the blank xml object I get the FormatException error.

How am I testing this incorrectly. Sample xml entry follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Form1>

  <Name Key="4/13/2015 3:22:05 PM">
    <Date>4/13/2015</Date>
    <JobNum>01det</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>testing</Task>
    <Start>12:30 PM</Start>
    <End>03:22 PM</End>
    <TotalTime>9828063</TotalTime>
  </Name>
  <Name Key="4/14/2015 6:36:06 AM">
    <Date>4/14/2015</Date>
    <JobNum>01det</JobNum>
    <RevNum>00000</RevNum>
    <Task>testing</Task>
    <Start>06:36 AM</Start>
    <End></End> \\THIS ONE WILL ALMOST ALWAYS BE BLANK DURING REGULAR BUSINESS HOURS
    <TotalTime></TotalTime>
  </Name>
</Form1>
```

Please advise and Thank You in advance. I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 public string sum()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        string test;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value != null)
            {
                test = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

                if (test != "")
                {
                    sum += double.Parse(test);
                }
            }                
        }
        return sum.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `string test = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();` provides me with a NullReference exception at the offending xml. Thank you though :-)

Comment: That's looking very good. I had forgotten about declaring string and then assigning it. I don't code for a living so there may be months in between. Thank You. You get the prize, but I'll definitely provide you more feedback. Thanks!! :-D

Comment: Can I talk you out of a up vote (bump) to one of my comments so I can do other site stuff?? :-D Please Please

Comment: Nah You don't have to. I need one vote to be able to do other stuff. Then I'm holding for 20 or 50. I can't remember. It's all Good. I'll keep you up to date on this though. Thank You again for your assistance. I really appreciate the help. :-D Have a Great Day!!