# Calculate From DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` like this:

[image]

How is the code to calculate data from `Column Total` and show it in a `Label`? It means the Label will show 2650

Comment: Yes, the vales could change and isn't loaded one time

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779729/how-i-can-show-the-sum-of-in-a-datagridview-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int total= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[x].Value); //x=column index 
}
label.text = sum.ToString();
```