# how to Gujarati Number Sum datagridview row in c#

Tags: c#

I can not sum of datagridview row. I can sum English numbers complete but gujarati number can't sum.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be several ways to achieve this.
One of them might be to add a hidden column with corresponding English number value, sum it and convert the result in Gujarati number.

Comment: I am sorry, I can only encourage you to take the lead and write your code yourself. There are plenty of examples available. Please use them to find the coding solution. Try these links [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893(v=vs.90).aspx)  [two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c24a0d7(v=vs.110).aspx) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779729/how-i-can-show-the-sum-of-in-a-datagridview-column)