# Calculate sum of a column in a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

I created a program which calculates the sum of a column in a datagridview, the problem arises when I refactor the logic from the click handler into a separate a method. The `calcSum` method does not seem to give me the correct output compared with `button2_Click` which has all the logic directly in the click handler.

Can anyone please point out what's wrong with my code?

```
//Calls sum of column method, "incorrect" output
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    calcSum(a,b,3);
}

private double calcSum(double a, double b, int c){
    foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows){
        a = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells[c].Value);
        b = b + a;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("sum is " = b.ToString());
    return b;
}

//shows correct/calculates output
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    double a =0,b=0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows){
        a = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells[3].Value);
        b = b + a;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Where are the values a and b declared or initialized?  Why are you passing them to your calcSum method?

Comment: Editted to try and make the dilemma clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method, you call the row "row" inside the loop, but declare it as r in the foreach.

I would recommend simplifying your code though.  Have a look at the answer here: [how I can show the sum of in a datagridview column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779729/how-i-can-show-the-sum-of-in-a-datagridview-column)

I don't think you need the a & b variables to get at your answer and perhaps you are initializing them differently in the 1st example when you are passing them into the method.

```
int a= 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows){
{
    a += Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[c].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing your parameters a and b are declared elsewhere.  If b has a value other then zero when you click the button, it will be added to the results.  Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    calcSum(3);
}

private double calcSum(int c){
    double a=0, b=0;
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows){
        a = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[c].Value);
        b = b + a;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("sum is " = b.ToString());
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    calcSum(out a,out b,3);
}

private double calcSum(out double a, out double b, int c){
    foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows){
        a = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells[c].Value);
        b = b + a;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("sum is " = b.ToString());
    return b;
}
```

You should read about [Out parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Answer (score -1):

First thought, it looks like a and b are global variables, you should reset them to zero