# Calculating 2 datagridview columns must be the same number of rows

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have 2 data grid views, one for Purchases and one for Sales

I sum the total of sales and subtract the total of purchases from it.

the problem is, it will only do the calculation if the number of rows of both datagridviews are the same, if one of them has more rows than the other, it will not give any value in the textbox where it should show the result

that's my code

```
private void GrossSale()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    }
    txtGrossSale.Text = sum.ToString();
}
private void NetSale()
{
    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    }
    txtNetSale.Text = sum2.ToString();
}
private void GrossPurchase()
{
    int sum3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum3 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    }
    txtGrossPurchase.Text = sum3.ToString();
}
private void NetPurchase()
{
    int sum4 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum4 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    }
    txtNetPurchase.Text = sum4.ToString();
}
private void TotalGross()
{
    int sum5 = 0;
    int sum6 = 0;
    int sum7 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum5 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        sum6 += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    }
    sum7 = sum5 + sum6;
    txtGross.Text = sum7.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Try with [Compute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead perhaps.

Comment: Thanks @JacobH for your reply, should I still use For with the compute ?

Comment: Do you have a datatable? That is key. If you do, then you just create 2 ints, compute the value and then subtract the ints. No loops needed. If you have no datatable then look at @Mark answer below.

Comment: Or heck, maybe just bind a datatable and forget the looping calculations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779835/7948962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at TotalGross().  You are looping over **dataGridView2**.Rows.Count, but are accessing both **dataGridView1**.Rows[i] AND dataGridView2.Rows[i] inside the loop...

Comment: so I should use For loop for each datagridview then calculate

Comment: That fixed the problem, Thanks

Comment: Exactly, you loop separately over each one.