# How to sum a column in Window application datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have below model class my orders table

```
public class OrdersModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int NoOfClothes { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int AdvancePayment { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
        public int SuitQty { get; set; }
        public OrdersModel()
        {

        }
```

I populate grid which works good. I want to sum the AdvancePayment and Price columns either to show in text box or in the last row. Below is my code to populate grid.

```
 DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            var CustomerId = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            List<OrdersModel> Orders = GlobalConfig.Connections.GetAllCustomerOrders(CustomerId);
            
            ordersModelBindingSource.DataSource = Orders;
```

I search for it but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, can't write comment's yet, but your question looks very similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779753/14569944